# Помогите разобраться с циклом for, не корректно работает

Tags: javascript, for

Перебираю массив циклом, по идеи положительные числа должны попадать в один массив, а отрицательные в другой. Но, когда я проверяю массив в котором должны быть только положительные числа, там лишние пробелы. С чем это связано?

```
function iqTest(numbers) {
      let evenNumber = []
  let oddNumber = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] % 2 === 1
              ? oddNumber.push(numbers[i])
              : evenNumber.push(numbers[i]);
      }
      return evenNumber
}

console.log(iqTest('2 4 7 8 10')); // 3
```

Comment: Вы строку проверяете а не массив чисел.

Comment: @nazarpunk да, да уже заметил)))) Спасибо большое за помощь)

Comment: И кажется, у вас там не положительные\отрицательные числа, а четные\нечетные :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
function iqTest(numbers) {
  let evenNumber = [];
  let oddNumber = [];
  numbers.split(' ').forEach(n => (n % 2 ? oddNumber : evenNumber).push(n));
  return evenNumber;
}

console.log(iqTest('2 4 7 8 10'));
```